# Liquid - if contains statement not working in for loop

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have a very basic conditional inside a loop that isn't working:

```
{% for tag in collections.all.tags %} 
     <li class="mb-1 ">
        <a class="text-white" title="{{ tag }}" href="#">
            {{ tag | handle }}
            {% if canonical_url contains tag | handle %}
                active
            {% endif %}
        </a>
     </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Right now, my `tag | handle` is "dodge" and if I print my `{{ canonical_url }}` I get `https://localhost:3000/collections/all/dodge` so my conditional should evaluate to truthy and print the word 'active'.

If I modify my statement to `{% if canonical_url contains 'dodge' %}` it works fine but I need it to be dynamic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to set handle into a variable and compare the variable instead of the handle? It's a suggestion; I am not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: Awesome! It worked perfectly, you want to answer the question officially?

Comment: Sure let me make into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the handle into a variable and use the variable for the comparison instead of the handle.

Answer (score 2):

First You have to assign value of tag handle to shopify liquid variable & then you will be able to use variable in condition And then every thing will be working fine & dynamic. Thanks !!